# Specifying Fetch mode for JPA Typed query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch, jpql, subquery

I am using JPA and Hibernate 3.6. I am trying to get my results from database in batch, reducing the number of selects in hibernate. In my class A there is a list of class B's objects. I have specified the fetchMode and only one Select is used to get all the objects of B.

```
public class A {    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="objectA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
}
public class C {
    int varC;
}
```

I want all the instances C to be returned in batch as well, one select statement to get all instances. I am using the following TypedQuery to get list of C objects. How can it be done ? Thanks for the help.

```
List<C> listC = em.createQuery("FROM C", C.class).getResultList();
```

---

To make it more clear, I have the following class C.

```
public class C {
        int varC;
    }
```

I want to fetch all the objects of C, "Select * from tableC". But when I use typedQuery it fires n select queries to get n objects of C. How can I make sure that it gets all the elements with one select statement. I just gave an example of class A, and Class B to show in other scenario I am able to get all the elements of B with one select statement.

Comment: when you say "when I use typedQuery" it refer to `createQuery("FROM C", C.class)`? and it will generate sql of multiple **select** by unique ID? can you post the sql generated by that hql then?

Comment: Yes, it refers to createQuery. I will post the select statement in some time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JPQL fetch syntax:

```
List<A> listA = em.createQuery("select distinct a from A a join fetch a.listB",
                  A.class).getResultList();
```

This will result in one SQL with join statement to populate your listB relationship.

The distinct keyword is required otherwise you'll get duplicates of A

Comment: Let's say I don't want list of B populated when I am getting listA. I will populate listB when I need it, which I am able to do now. My requirement is to just get list of A objects with single SELECT. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: That is called lazy fetching, you need to set `@OneToMany(mappedBy="objectA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetchType = LAZY)`

Comment: I have edited my question, to make it clear. I don't want anything to do with class B objects.

Answer (score 0):

there is no relation between A and C, C is a table with only 1 attribute and no join. if you want to get C from A you must join it with A and give something like your `List<B> listB` variable in A. so it became something like `List<C> listC` or `C sinlgeC` in your class A